# Override background color of selected Tab in material-ui (version 1.0.0-beta.29)

Tags: material-ui

I am trying change the background color of a Tab, when it is selected. I tried overriding the classes using the below `classes` prop and nothing worked! Am I missing something or this is something not possible?

```
classes={{
  rootInherit: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff' 
  },
  rootPrimary: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff' 
  },
  rootPrimarySelected: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff' 
  },
  rootPrimaryDisabled: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff' 
  },
  rootSecondary: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff'
  },
  rootSecondarySelected: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff'
  },
  rootSecondaryDisabled: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff' 
  },
  rootInheritSelected: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff' 
  },
  rootInheritDisabled: {
    backgroudColor: '#0000ff'
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this is absolutely possible. To change the color of the selected `Tab`, you'll need to set a `backgroundColor` and override the `rootSecondarySelected`, `rootPrimarySelected`, `rootInheritSelected` classes on each individual `Tab` component:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  colorfulTabs: {
    backgroundColor: "#00ff00",
  },
});

<Tabs>
  <Tab
    classes={{
      rootInheritSelected: classes.colorfulTabs,
      rootPrimarySelected: classes.colorfulTabs,
      rootSecondarySelected: classes.colorfulTabs
    }}
    label="Item One"
  />
  <Tab
    classes={{
      rootInheritSelected: classes.colorfulTabs,
      rootPrimarySelected: classes.colorfulTabs,
      rootSecondarySelected: classes.colorfulTabs
    }}
    label="Item Two" />
  <Tab 
    classes={{
      rootInheritSelected: classes.colorfulTabs,
      rootPrimarySelected: classes.colorfulTabs,
      rootSecondarySelected: classes.colorfulTabs
    }}
  label="Item Three" />
</Tabs>
```

The `rootInheritSelected` class will apply to `Tabs` where no `textColor` prop has been set (i.e., the text color is inherited from the parent). The `rootPrimarySelected` class will apply to `Tabs` where `textColor` is `primary`, and `rootSecondarySelected` to `secondary`.